# How do I rename a JavaScript Image() and create a completely different Image()?

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing

I have 2 images:

- A 250 x 250 px white square (image1.png)
- A 250 x 250 px black square (image2.png)

I want to create a new image using JavaScript that is called image3.png

```
var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "image1.png";
image3.src = "image2.png";
```

When this code is run Google Chrome saves these images locally because they are used in the process of creating the Image().

[image: Google Chromes Resource Viewer]

Is there any way to transform the **image3** into **image3.png** and **prevent Google Chrome from saving image1.png and image2.png** in the process?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @minitech I am trying to find a way to overwrite images so I can prevent users from downloading images. If I can make it so a user only sees an image if they mouseover a thumbnail, and overwrite that image when they mouseaway I could prevent them from going into the Google Chrome Developer Tool to download the original image from the pages saved resources.

Comment: That’s just not possible. For a user to see an image, they will need to be able to download it in some form. Just try not to bother, or watermark the full version, or something.

Comment: @minitech I understand that deleting an image from cache with JavaScript isn't possible, but how can I create a new image with the same name that replaces the old one?

Comment: You can’t! (Unless you find a hash collision, maybe.) Even serving up a different image from the same path on consecutive loads will put them in different temporary files if the browser uses those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your code doesn’t actually look like that and both images are used, no. You can’t stop a browser from downloading those images; it needs to have them to show them.